# Add a jquery preloader on form submission

Tags: forms, jquery, preloader

I am asynchronously submitting my form using jquery and AJAX . Refer the code below

```
$("#save_report").click(function()
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : actionOfForm,
                        type : $('#custom_targeting_param_form').attr("method"),
                        data : $('#custom_targeting_param_form').serialize(),
                        success : function(){
                            alert('Report Saved successfully');
                            $("#showOrExportCustomTargetingReport").val('showReport');  
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
```

I have got a link in my html with the id **save_report** and on clicking the link an Ajax call is being made to the URL which is passed as the **actionOfForm** variable as shown above.

Till this everything is fine. But now I want to get a preloader image/text like **loading..** while the form submission is taking place in the background . And I want to show it in an alert box , not on my html ...

*as i am a new user sorry for not able to post the image, but i hope i am comprehendable*

Once the form submission is done , the preloader image will be gone and replaced with the success message alert.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: what do you mean by `i want to show it in alert box`?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can have your image in a div..intially hide it..

```
<div id="imgDiv" style="display:none"><img src="/img.png"/><div>
```

then on click on your link(on AJAX call)..show this div on top of page(you have to use some css property for this).like this-

```
$("#save_report").click(function()
                {
                    $('#imgDiv').show();// show your loading image
                 $.ajax({
                        url : actionOfForm,
                        type : $('#custom_targeting_param_form').attr("method"),
                        data : $('#custom_targeting_param_form').serialize(),
                        success : function(){
                            alert('Report Saved successfully');
                            $('#imgDiv').hide();// hide your image after successful call 
                             $("#showOrExportCustomTargetingReport").val('showReport');  
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
```

Comment: @vivekI actually want to display it as an alert / as a dialog box , can anything of that sort be achieved using jquery . I haven't worked with dialog boxes in jQuery as of now.

Comment: I did the same without using any dialog boxes , but I have a peculiar problem now.  The ajax form submit is working fine in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome .  In FF/Chrome , the link is not working on the first click , but when I click the second time , it shows two success alerts . Why is that happening ? Guys any solution?

Comment: I had even used **event.preventDefault** but to no use.